# Fat Free framework set variable from template

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

I am trying to set a SESSION variable in Fat Free framework from a view.

My code now is: 
    `<set SESSION.regex_save_successful="false" />`

That doesn't work, this doesn't work either
    `<set SESSION.regex_save_successful=false />`

Neither does this:
    `<set @SESSION.regex_save_successful=(")false(") />`

If anyone can help me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Maybe there are some other solutions to my problem: I would like to reset the variable when the view is loaded and the `<check>` is executed. It now says after first reroute: Successful saved. Then after every reload it needs to be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template engine copies the variables into a new environment ("the sandbox") before rendering a template. As result your code is only modifying the copy instead of the `SESSION` variable which gets mapped to the global `$_SESSION` variable responsible for session management.

Although it's a bad decision to let the template modify session information, here is a possible solution:

```
{~ Base::instance()->set('SESSION.regex_save_successful', false); ~}
```

Comment: What would you recommend for my problem then? It just needs to display once. And when it doesn't save again, just don't show it.

Comment: Let the controller modify the session and add a variable for displaying or hiding the message. This approach keeps your template clean from unexpected side effects.